# PHP unable to show jpg image, shows black screen with small rectangle inside

Tags: php, jpeg

Trying to open a jpeg image in any browser and it won't show, shows a black screen with a small white rectangle in it.

[image]

I've tried setting errors display in php.ini and increasing the memory size. The jpg file is only 219 KB.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, no errors pop up and it fails to open on IE, chrome, or firefox.
I've also checked under the IIS manager under the MIME.types to check if the extension "jpeg, jpg, jpe" was listed there and they are. Below is my PHP code:

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = file_get_contents($file);
echo $image; 
//readme($file) <-- also fails
```

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same thing happen in my project where uploaded image after success provide url and when open it, it showa as above image. API build in .net and image is uploading from Android using okhttp multipart. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, solved this issue by adding below ob clean while loop after header

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
/*It will clean output buffer*/
while (ob_get_level() && @ob_end_clean()) {
        ;
}
$image = file_get_contents($file);
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a semicolon in the first line

```php
$file = 'test.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = file_get_contents($file);
echo $image; 
//readme($file) <-- also fails
```

Comment: That was a typo, on my lines of code I do have the semi-colon at the end but I still only get a black screen.

Comment: Please check the path of the image, or .htaccess config

Comment: I echoed the path out and copied and pasted it into a windows explorer and it opened. I searched for the .htaccess file using agent ransack and found it under a subfolder within inetpub called kanboard which is our task board manager application we use. We are using Windows r2 2012 server, where else would the .htaccess file be?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, somehow there was an echo calling an empty space before this bit of code was executed, had to use `ob_start()` at the very top and `ob_end_clean()` just before executing the headers to allow for the jpeg image to show.